# White listed static block is not displaying in home page

Tags: static-block, ce-1.9.2.2, directive-whitelist, whitelist

After upgarding to 1.9.2.2 the `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home-news-text" template="cms/content.phtml"}}` in home page is not displaying the content of the block. I have added the block id in white list but still not appearing. What step am I missing?

[image]

Comment: How did you add it? What does the entry look like? DId you flush the cache inbetween?

Comment: Navigating to System => Permissions => Blocks I added the block name and set the allowed to yes, then I refresh the cache or even diabled the cache but still no changes

Comment: So, you added "cms/block"? Any errors in your logs?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: block  in /mypath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php on line 197 which I guess it's not related to this

Comment: Do any of your other cms blocks work?

Comment: Could you please update your question, maybe with a screenshot of your System => Permissions > Blocks section?

Comment: I will update ... none of the cms blocks in home page works

Comment: From you screenshot I can see: "cms/block" is missing as entry there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enter the `block type="cms/block"` instead of the `block_id="home-news-text"` into the permission form for your blocks to show up.